# Trouble converting SQL query to django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I am trying to convert this SQL query (which works flawlessly in mySQL) to Django ORM so that it can be used in a PostgreSQL environment (as the SQL query is invalid for PG).  I have tried several different ways using aggregate and annotate but I just can't figure it out.

What I am trying to do is count the number of entries of each type (there are 3 types in total), in each month, 6 months either side of the current date!

The working SQL query is

```
    select count(c.id) as Quantity, date_format(expiry, '%Y-%m') as Expiry, type from certificate as c
join type as t on t.id = c.type_id
where expiry >= date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 6 month), '%Y-%m-%d')
and expiry <= date_format(date_add(now(), interval 6 month), '%Y-%m-%d')
group by month(expiry), type
order by expiry asc
```

I changed the 'date_format' into a postgres 'to_char' but then I can't seem to group by 'month(expiry)' and an ORM solution seems to be a much better way to go.

The main Certificate model is as follows:

```
class Certificate(models.Model):
    epc_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_index=False)
    building_area = models.IntegerField(db_index=False)
    building_emissions = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, db_index=False)
    energy_usage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, db_index=False)
    refrig_weight = models.IntegerField(db_index=False)
    ac_output = models.IntegerField(db_index=False)
    annual_heating = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50, db_index=False)
    renewable_heating = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50, db_index=False)
    annual_electric = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50, db_index=False)
    typical_heating = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50, db_index=False)
    typical_electric = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50, db_index=False)
    renewable_electric = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50, db_index=False)

    expiry = models.DateField(db_index=True) # This is the expiry date used

    manager = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100, db_index=False)
    rrn = models.ForeignKey(RRN, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    postcode = models.ForeignKey(Postcode, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    heating = models.ForeignKey(Heating, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    complexity = models.ForeignKey(Complexity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    environment = models.ForeignKey(Environment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assessor = models.ForeignKey(Assessor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scheme = models.ForeignKey(Scheme, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'certificate'
```

And this table has a foreign key link to the 'type' table which models as follows:

```
class Type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=25, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'type'
```

There are 3 'types' within the Type table (I know, confusing naming conventions) which are 'EPC', 'TM44' & 'DEC'.  As I said, I am trying to count the number of each type within each month over the period of a year?

Any help would be much appreciated, I have been trying to convert this for about 2-3 weeks now and have finally decided to ask for help.  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
So I should of added what I have tried...I'm not really understanding where I can use the aggregate function in this query but with annotate I managed:

```
currentDate = datetime.now().date()
prev_half_year = currentDate - relativedelta(months=6)
next_half_year = currentDate + relativedelta(months=6)
expiryObj = Certificate.objects.filter(expiry__range=[prev_half_year, next_half_year]).annotate(epc_count=Count('id', filter=Q(type__type='EPC'))).count()
```

I added the count on the end which returned a integer of 151 (this could be correct I can't be sure as this is the query I need to figure out so I can check).  The problem is i am unsure if this is the correct figure for the whole year and also i don't see how to add a group_by statement to get the individual months.  If i add it to the end such as count().group_by('expiry')" i get "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'group_by'" and if I add it before the count I get "AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'group_by'"! Also, the SQL query is able to group by Month(expiry) but I haven't found any documentation that relates to how to convert this to Django ORM.

**Further Edit**
Thankyou to 'iklinac' for some hints on where to look.  I have managed to further the results using this query:

```
results = Certificate.objects.filter(expiry__range=[prev_half_year, next_half_year]).values_list('expiry__year', 'expiry__month').annotate(Sum('type_id')).order_by('expiry__year')
```

This returns a queryset of ---- <QuerySet [(2020, 6, 30), (2020, 7, 45), (2020, 8, 114), (2020, 9, 67), (2020, 10, 111), (2020, 11, 80), (2020, 12, 85), (2021, 1, 108), (2021, 2, 49), (2021, 3, 75), (2021, 4, 91), (2021, 5, 65), (2021, 6, 68)]> --- which appears to be close to what I'm looking for in that the months searched are correct but the sum value (3rd entry in tuple) don't appear to relate to anything?  I performed the query on the website manually for the month of June 2020 (which states 30 entries in the returned query) however, the site returns only 8 entries??
[Picture of Website Manual Query Returned Values Differ From ORM Returned Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOFJ0.jpg)

Comment: What did you try? where did you fail.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/ | https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/ | https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions

Comment: Postgres does not have `date_add` and `date_sub`. Use something like: `select now() - interval 6 month; select now() + interval 6 month;` Also `month` would need to be changed to `select date_part('month', now() - interval '6 months'); 6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. Only a small change is required.
Instead of `Sum('type_id')` use `Count('type_id')` to get the count

```
results = Certificate.objects.filter(
    expiry__range=[prev_half_year, next_half_year]).values_list(
        'expiry__year', 'expiry__month').annotate(Count('type_id')).order_by('expiry__year')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... unfortunately this is still returning the same tuple --> (2020, 6, 3603) -- which is correctly counting the total records which expire that month but I just can't figure out how to separate the last element of the tuple into individual type ids (there should be 3 of them).  Cheers for trying.

Comment: Ah ha... but you did put me onto something...changing the values_list to include 'values_list('expiry__year', 'expiry__month', 'type__type')' with your Count addition solved it.  Thankyou so much this has been bugging me for weeks.